# BagWriter and BagReader attribute not found in rosbag2_py

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, rosbag2

I'm using ROS2-humble. I would like to create a Program in VSC using python that can manually write data into a Rosbag. Apparently to write i need the attribute BagWriter from rosbag2_py. I tried that by using `from rosbag2_py import BagWriter` however once i start the code i get the error message "AttributeError: module 'rosbag2_py' has no attribute 'BagWriter'". Same for BagReader which i wanted to use to learn the general structure of a Rosbag file. I need the writer in order to make a converter that takes data from ADTFdat files and writes them into Rosbag files in order to use ROS2 funtionalities.
Any idea how i could solve the Bagwriter problem? I've already tried to install the Bagwriter by doing "pip install rosbag2_py --upgrade"
Any help highly appreciated.